# How to connect to oracle using jdbc

Tags: jsp, jdbc, oracle11g, java-14

I am trying to connect to Oracle from jsp using jdbc. but the `class.forName(...)` throws exception
the full code is here:

```
%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.sql.*, javax.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        //DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "ic", "ic");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        out.println("connection established successfully...!!");        
    }catch(Exception e){
        out.println("Error: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    
    %>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Using  - JDK 14.0.2, JDBC14.jar, Tomcat9, Oracle 11g xe.
may be the jdbc14.jar file is not placed at the right location.
any sugession?
thanks in advance

Comment: What is jdbc14.jar? Do you mean ojdbc14.jar? If so, please be aware that is for Java 1.4, not Java 14. Also, please include the full exception stacktrace in your question (use `e.printStackTrace(out)`, though you might want to add some formatting, or log it instead).

Comment: You are right, it's ojdbc14.jar. Then what is the compatible jdbc driver for jdk 14

Comment: Use Maven artifiact `com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11:21.1.0.0` (ojdbc11 is for Java 11, leave it to Oracle to mess up naming ;). Or look at https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.oracle.database.jdbc if you need an earlier version. You can also download drivers at https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by putting the ojdbc10.jar file into the tomcat lib folder.